# How to check installed fonts styles?

Tags: c++, winapi, mfc

I need a list of all installed fonts in the client machine (Always Windows) that contain the styles **bold**, *italic* and ***bold* *italic***. Is there a function for that?

I'm already able to list all installed fonts with `EnumFontFamiliesEx` and i suppose that is possible to filter that list, but i'm looking for a "better way" :)

Thanks!
**PS:** I'm using C++ with MFC.

**EDIT:**
For fonts that doesn't have these styles Windows can "fake" that behavior (force a font look bold or italic), but i need to know which fonts really have these styles.

Comment: On https://msdn.microsoft.com/fr-fr/library/windows/desktop/dd162620(v=vs.85).aspx I just found this in Remarks : 
`lfCharSet = DEFAULT_CHARSET
lfFaceName = a specific font ||
Enumerates all character sets and styles in a specific font.`

Comment: @rak007 I will have to check font by font for the styles, but i believe that is the best and only option. i was kinda hoping for a function that would bring all font with those styles. Thanks!

Comment: @BarmakShemirani as far i understand not all fonts have italic and bold options, windows can "fake" these behavior, but i need to know which fonts really have these options so i can embed them in a PDF.

Comment: That's true. You should put that information in the question to clarify that you are doing something in PDF

Comment: Asking for a *"better way"* without explaining what *"better"* means to you does not constitute an answerable question. Please see [ask].

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As you are using "EnumFontFamiliesEx",the call back function recieves the structure LOGFONT....

`LOGFONT` has two variables `lfWeight` and `lfItalic`.

Use those two variables to check if the enumerated font has style or not.

if `lfWeight` value is 0 (`FW_DONTCARE`) and `lfItalic` is false, you can consider this do not have any style.

Or if you want to be very specific, for example, you want to consider fonts with only Bold and Regular, then you can validate, if  `lfWeight`  has value from {400 (REGULAR), 600 (BOLD), 700 (BOLD), 800 (BOLD)}

Below link has all the details.

https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/dd145037(v=vs.85).aspx